# How to add constant string to __doc__ for all class methods?

Tags: python, documentation, docstring

I have code that looks like this:

```
constString = """
Default docstring info:
    1
    2
    3"""

class A():

    def A1():
        """
        First unique docstring.
        """
        pass

    def A2():
        """
        Second unique docstring.
        """
        pass
B = A()
print(B.A1.__doc__)
```

If I run this code I recive output:

```
First unique docstring.

Second unique docstring.
```

But I want to replace method's docstring by adding constString for all methods in class A. The output must looks like this:

```
First unique docstring.
Default docstring info:
1
2
3

Second unique docstring.
Default docstring info:
1
2
3
```

How I can do it?

Comment: So to be clear, by "replace" you really mean "concatenate"?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to override `YourClass.__doc__` and append the string there?

Comment: Yes, I mean concatenate constString to all docstring in class A methods.

Comment: How to override? if I use:  B.A1.__doc__ += constString    - then recive exception

Comment: @TimurGilmullin: Sorry, you can only mark *one* of the answers as accepted, not both. Glad you found both answers to be helpful!

Comment: Yes, both answers are usable. Thank you too) But, I used short answer in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instancemethod's docstring is taken from the underlying function, which is why `B.A1.__doc__ += constString` doesn't work. However:

```
B.A1.__func__.__doc__ += constString
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: For whatever reason `B` is an instance of `A`, not a class. So `B.A1` is a bound method in any version of Python.

Comment: Oh crumbs, so it is. I was focusing on the class only.

Answer (score 5):

Function docstrings are writable; just assign to `function.__doc__`; here is a decorator that adds a string to the docstring of all methods on a class:

```
import inspect

def add_documentation(doc):
    if not doc.startswith('\n'):
        doc = '\n' + doc

    def decorator(cls):
        for func in filter(inspect.isfunction, vars(cls).values()):
            func.__doc__ += doc
        return cls

    return decorator
```

Use this like so:

```
@add_documentation(constString)
class A:
    def A1(self):
        """
        First unique docstring.
        """
        pass

    def A2(self):
        """
        Second unique docstring.
        """
        pass
```

The decorator works in both Python 2 and 3 and will only affect methods defined directly on the class, not on any base classes.